# Как разложить json ответ

Tags: python, json, requests, eval

Есть вот такой ответ от сервера

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "msg": "",
  "code": 0,
  "data": [{
    "id": 324,
    "emp": 6,
    "emp_code": "6",
    "first_name": "wsrhedth",
    "last_name": null,
    "department": "Отдел",
    "position": null,
    "punch_time": "2024-01-29 07:51:26",
    "punch_state": "0",
    "punch_state_display": "Приход",
    "verify_type": 15,
    "verify_type_display": "Лицо",
    "work_code": "0",
    "gps_location": null,
    "area_alias": "123",
    "terminal_sn": "CN9B213760020",
    "temperature": 0.0,
    "is_mask": "Нет",
    "terminal_alias": "Auto add",
    "upload_time": "2024-01-29 07:51:25"
  }, {
    "id": 325,
    "emp": 7,
    "emp_code": "7",
    "first_name": "dxgdgh",
    "last_name": null,
    "department": "Отдел",
    "position": null,
    "punch_time": "2024-01-29 08:54:28",
    "punch_state": "0",
    "punch_state_display": "Приход",
    "verify_type": 15,
    "verify_type_display": "Лицо",
    "work_code": "0",
    "gps_location": null,
    "area_alias": "123",
    "terminal_sn": "CN9B213760020",
    "temperature": 0.0,
    "is_mask": "Нет",
    "terminal_alias": "Auto add",
    "upload_time": "2024-01-29 08:54:27"
  }]
}
```

Как можно получить 3 переменные по блокам(punch_state,first_name,punch_time), это часть в data?
Пробовал так:

```
response = requests.get(url,params=json, headers=headers)
str = eval(response.text)
str2 = str['id']
print(str)
```

но такой способ не работает

Comment: Какой именно punch_time? Их тут вообще-то два

Comment: print(response.json()[ 'data'][0]['id'])

Comment: @СергейШ спасибо то что нужно